# How to split integer into group of 3 digits in python?

Tags: python, integer

```
n = 136462380542525933949347185849942359177
```

how to split it into group of 3 digits?
the result that i want is

```
136, 462, 380, ..., 177
```

Comment: you can treat it like a string and split it. if you want to treat it like a nr, well, some math ops: divide, subtract etc

Comment: `v = str(n);size = 3;res = [int(v[i:i + size]) for i in range(0, len(v), size)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex one-liner.

```
import re

# match 3 digits or 1-3 digits at the end
ls = re.findall(r"(\d{3}|\d{1,3}$)", str(n))
```

**Result**

```
print(ls)
# ['136', '462', '380', '542', '525', '933', '949', '347', '185', '849', '942', '359', '177']
```

This solution also extracts the last 1 or 2 digits if n has (3m+1) or (3m+2) digits.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d{1,3}', str(n))` works just as well

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. `\d{1,3}` should be greedy and match 3 chars if possible LOL.

Answer (score -1):

```py
n = 136462380542525933949347185849942359177
s = str(n)
a = []
for i in range(0, len(s) - 2):
    a.append(s[i: i + 3])
print(a)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.